# Google Calendar API: Clear All Events From Secondary Calendar PHP

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to clear the contents of a secondary Google Calendar in PHP but I see in the API documentation that the clear() method only works on the accounts primary calendar and wont take parameters for a secondary calendar calendar ID. Instead it says to use the delete() method but I do not want to delete the calendar all together, just delete its contents.

```
//legal 
$service->calendars->clear('primary');
//Illegal
$service->calendars->clear($calendarId);
```

What would be the most effective way to clearing the events of a secondary calendar in the API?

Comment: I tried fetching individual Id's and deleting each event one by one but it does not delete any events from today just all days after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually delete events from your secondary calendar like you would in your primary. Use the [Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) and provide the `calendarid` and `eventId`. But, take note that in your secondary calendar, your calendarId is no longer your default email. It's different. (Calendar-> calendar settings -> Calendar Address )
You can give it a Try-it to test this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The only issue is that I would like to preserve the calendarid as this is an automated system